# Unity: suddenly some gameobjects stopped beeing shown

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d-games, gameobject

I'm a Computer Science 
Engineering student. I'm currently working on a Uni project using Unity to build a 2D game. Until this morning everything was fine, but suddenly after some work on a UI Manager Script in my menu scene (Scene 0) when I tried to play the game some gameobjects (apparently random) stopped to be visualized on Scene View and on Game View in the Level scene (Scene 1).
I can see all gameobjects fine on camera preview and they all are active in the hierarchy, even all colliders are working.

I tried to look on the web, but I can't find any solution or any similar case...
I don't really have any ideas, I'll be really glad if someone can help me. Thanks.

Comment: Could be a lot of things. For things not showing up in the scene view, make sure you don't have object that are hidden in the hierarchy (Unity 2019 show up as a eye icon left of an gameObject in the hierarchy). For the game view, if you can see the objects in the preview try and use the frame debugger (Window->Analysis->Frame Debugger) when in play mode,click enable, then select scroll from top to bottom in the list (basically it the order all elements are renderer and you get a preview). That way you can check if something is rendering on top of your missing elements.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the answer. It's a problem with the rendering order. Can you please specify (if you know) how to change the rendering order so I can solve the problem?

Comment: Please, provide more informations or screenshots of the situation.

Comment: Hi Federico, actually Leo Quint answer showed me that the problem is in the rendering order. But I don't know how to change this order...

Comment: Unity will render object based on their shader's render queue (you can check that on the material, smaller number = rendered first) then based on the distance from the camera (if something is closer to a camera it gets rendered after things that are further away). For shaders usually you have a few main one like opaque (2000 gets rendered early) or transparent (3000 rendered later). Also remember that for distance from the camera you have too look not at the gameobject's position but its closest vertices (i.e. a cube at (0,0,0) has vertices at positions in all 4 directions)

Comment: In this project every gameobject use the same Default shader (so the queue number is the same for every gameobject). Also I have a backup copy of this project (very old) in which the Z position and so the distances from the camera are the same of this new version. So I don't know what can I change to make it render properly again...

Comment: Make sure that if you want object a to be on top (render wise) of object b that it is in front of it Z wise. Objects at the same positions may or may not always render in the same order. As an example you may have everything rendering perfectly all the time in unity but once built on device the order may be completely different. Also things like rotation (even a tiny amount) will change the position of vertices and can then change the rendering order. Also also you only have 1 camera? because each camera have their own render order and render based of their depth.

Comment: Solved changing the Z position of an element. I still don't understand why with position Z = 0 this morning was working and now it's working only with pos Z = 83. Anyway now it seems to work, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Material variable on the Sprite Renderer component and make sure it's set to "Sprites-Default". In my case, the material for the hidden objects had somehow changed to "None" while I was working on a little postprocessing effect.

Edit: Here's how the material changed. Adding a SpriteGlow script from a package which works with postprocessing had first turned the objects' SpriteRenderer material from the original "Sprites-Default" to "Sprite/Outline". Upon removing the SpriteGlow script component from the object, the material became "None" rather than defaulting back to "Sprites-Default" and that was when I stopped seeing the objects even though they were present in the scene. This is most likely your problem too since you said every other thing like collision works and the objects are definitely present in the scene.